# setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Estou com um programa em python e opencv que lê uma imagem e depois verifica as cores da imagem em cada posição de dois `for` aninhados. Como estou fazendo um `threshold` na imagem pra facilitar na verificação retornará uma imagem binária. E não consigo achar algo que me ajude nesse contexto de processamento de imagens. O erro acontece no momento em que vou executar o `if`, no qual aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> setting an array element with a sequence.

Código:

```
asfaltoMax = np.array([108, 109, 111]) 
asfaltoMin = np.array([175, 175, 175])
terraMax = np.array([33, 62, 123])
terraMin = np.array([163, 169, 206])

img = cv2.imread("IF24-6-2015.jpg")
imgThresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

largura = int(img.shape[1])
altura = int(img.shape[0])
qntPixels = largura * altura

auxCor = np.empty([1,3])
auxAsfalto = np.empty([1,3])
auxTerra = np.empty([1,3])

contAsfalto = 0
contTerra = 0
linhas = 0
colunas = 0
cont = 0

for i in range(largura):
    for j in range(altura):
        #auxCor em B, G, R
        auxCor = imgThresh
        print("Imagem na posição i,j: {}".format(auxCor))
        -->if auxCor >= asfaltoMin and auxCor <= asfaltoMax:
            print("Cor BGR do pixel: {}, posição i: {}, j: {}".format(auxCor, i, j))
        print("Iteração: {}, auxCor: {}".format(cont, auxCor))
        break
    cont += 1




cv2.imshow("Imagem", imgThresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**EDIT**

```
...Código anterior...
for i in range(largura):
    for j in range(altura):
        #auxCor em B, G, R

        print("Imagem na posição i,j: {}".format(auxCor))
        -->if cv2.inRange(imgThresh, asfaltoMin, asfaltoMax, auxCor): #The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
            print("Cor BGR do pixel: {}, posição i: {}, j: {}".format(auxCor, i, j))
        print("Iteração: {}, auxCor: {}".format(cont, auxCor))
        break
    cont += 1
```

**EDIT 2**

```
somenteAsfalto = cv2.inRange(img, asfaltoMin, asfaltoMax)
somenteTerra = cv2.inRange(img, terraMin, terraMax)
for i in range(altura):
    for j in range(largura):
        if somenteAsfalto[i, j] == 1: #Nunca entra
            print("Tem asfalto em i: {}, j: {}".format(i,j))
        if somenteTerra[i, j] == 1: #Nunca entra
            print("Tem terra em i: {}, j: {}".format(i, j))
    cont += 1
```

**Imagem**

[image: Imagem usada para teste]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagens em OpenCV sáo arrays, voce está esquecendo de usar os indices do array para pegar a cor

```
 #auxCor em B, G, R
 auxCor = imgThresh[i, j]
```

Nao sei se o seu trabalho é só um exercicio, mas voce pode usar a funcao [cv2.inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) do opencv para saber se uma cor esta dentro de determinado intervalo

Edit: Atualizando a resposta. O threshold te retorna 2 valores (um retval e a imagem binarizada). Na linha do threshold vc deve ignorar o retval pra pegar só a imagem:

```
_, imgThresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Edit2: O inRange eh na imagem inteira, caso voce va usar ele, nao precisa do threshold:

```
asfaltoMax = np.array([108, 109, 111]) 
asfaltoMin = np.array([175, 175, 175])
terraMax = np.array([33, 62, 123])
terraMin = np.array([163, 169, 206])

img = cv2.imread("IF24-6-2015.jpg")
somenteAsfalto = cv2.inRange(img, asfaltoMin, asfaltoMax)
somenteTerra = cv2.inRange(img, terraMin, terraMax)

for i in range(img.shape[0]):
   for j in range(img.shape[1]):
       if somenteAsfalto[i, j] == 1:
           print ("tem asfalto em %d - %d" % (i, j))
```

Comment: Quando eu uso os índices como imgThresh[i,j] aparece o seguinte erro: "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple". E quando uso como imgThresh[i][j] aparece esse erro: "'float' object is not subscriptable". O cv2.inRange eu imaginava que era apenas para vídeo.

Comment: O opencv te retorna uma tupla, por padrao, a primeira posicao eh um numero e a segunda é a imagem em si, vou atualizar a resposta para levar isso em consideração.

Comment: Após feito isso aparece o seguinte erro: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". Eu não vejo sentido utilizar esses métodos dentro do inRange. O que pode ser feito? Obs: vou atualizar a pergunta

Comment: A questao eh que na imagem binarizada o pixel tem somente um valor (entre 0 e 255), e voce esta testando com um array de 3 posicoes (asfaltoMax, aslfatoMin) e o numpy nao sabe comparar 1 valor com 3

Comment: No EDIT 2 o não tá entrando no if. O for executa mas nunca entra no if

Comment: Ae tem que ver os seus valores minimos e maximos. Nao tem como compartilhar a imagem?

Comment: Irei colocar na pergunta

Comment: O max e o min estao invertidos, asfaltoMax deveria ser asfaltoMin e vice-versa. Tambem para o terraMin e terraMax. Um erro meu eh que o inRange retorna 255 quando esta dentro do range, nao 1. Entao o if deveria ser somenteAsfalto[i, j] == 255

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87888/discussion-between-marcos-paulo-s-rezende-and-begnini).